# Data sources related to Federal regulation

Tags: data-mining, references

I'm looking for sources of data related to Federal regulation and enforcement.  Things like the following:

- Size of Federal regulatory agencies (number of workers)
- Number of pages of Federal regulations [total pages that are in force; not just new ones]
- Number of enforcement actions brought by various agencies
- Cost of complying with regulations

Can anyone tell me where I might find such information?

Answer (score 3):

This is the kind of thing regularly compiled by US proponents of smaller government.

For example [this source](http://extent-of-regulation.dhwritings.com/) suggests US Federal Regulations were 304.5 inches (interesting unit; just over 25 feet) in 2008.  Compare with [this source](http://usgovinfo.about.com/od/uscongress/a/fedregulations_2.htm) giving "134,723 pages in 201 volumes that claimed 19 feet of shelf space" in 1998, compared with 54,834 pages in 1970.

It is not clear whether there was the same density of regulations in the different years (presumably measured in pages per foot, from the country that uses the acre-foot as a measure of volume).

Answer (score 2):

www.data.gov is probably your best place to start looking for curated data on the subject. I wouldn't necessarily trust third-party data on the subject, unless you can source their numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There's [an API in development](http://christophergandrud.blogspot.fr/2012/09/federal-register-apir-package-ideas.html) on your topic.